# Using different Contexts for getting SharedPreference

Tags: android

Is there a difference in using

`getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences()` vs `this.getSharedPreferences()` for creating a SharedPreference object.  NOTE: `this` implies activity here

I'm aware that `getSharedPreferences()` is inherited from `Context` class and `Application` and `Activity` are both subclasses of `Context`.

Is the functionality same for above both unlike `Toasts` and `ProgressDialogues` where we are supposed to use only `Activity Context`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Activity` `Context` unless you want to use `SharedPreferences` object globally. `getApplicationContext()` and `this` differs by their lifecycle.
If you use `getApplicationContext()` to create object for `SharedPreferences` you can make use of that object throughout the application. But if you only want to use `SharedPreferences` object in an activity go for `Activity` `Context`